# Cell Merge in HTML Table without changing the structure of the table

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a couple of columns and rows in my HTML Table.

I need to merge two cells, and show the first cell data Though two cell having data. Without changing the table structure.

Please see the two screen shots below.

**Html Table with all cells having data:**

[image: AllCells]

**Merged the cells though all cells having data:**

[image: Merged Cells]

Code

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      First Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Second Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Third Column
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Second Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Third Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Forth Cell
    </td>
    <td ColSpan=2>
      Fifth Cell
    </td>
    <td ColSpan=2>
      Sixth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Seventh Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Eighth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Ninth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code with us, have you tried `colspan`.

Comment: I have tried with colspan. But my Table structure was changed.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you only need to hide the sixth cell

Possible example:

```css
td[ColSpan]+td{display:none;
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      First Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Second Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Third Column
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Second Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Third Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Forth Cell
    </td>
    <td ColSpan=2>
      Fifth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Sixth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Seventh Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Eighth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Ninth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You may also look at display:grid and display:contents to redefine the table-layout into a grid-layout , and still display:none for the sixth cell to hide.

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  width: max-content;
  padding: 2px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

tbody,
tr {
  display: contents;
}

tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      First Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Second Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Third Column
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Second Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Third Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Forth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Fifth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Sixth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Seventh Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Eighth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Ninth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With javscript, you can add the attribute colspan and also hide the sixth cell :

```js
let rowCellSpan = document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(3) >:nth-child(2)");
let rowCellHidden = document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(3) >:nth-child(3)");
rowCellHidden.style.display = "none";
rowCellSpan.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      First Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Second Column
    </th>
    <th>
      Third Column
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Second Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Third Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Forth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Fifth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Sixth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Seventh Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Eighth Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Ninth Cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```